# CodeIgniter upload txt doc - The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, mime-types

CodeIngiter version: 2.2

I'm developing a PHP API and I'm trying to upload a file. The code is:

```
    $config['upload_path'] = $path;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|jpe|pdf|doc|docx|rtf|text|txt';
    $config['max_size'] = '4096';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '1024';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = true;

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('upload', $config);

    $CI->upload->do_upload("file")
```

It works with image files and pdf files, but when I try to upload a .txt o .doc file I got the error: filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed

I'm doing the test with Postman tool (form-data mode). I have checked the mimes.php file and it seems right.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: In `Postman` submit form with `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: How I can submit files using "x-www-form-urlencoded"? it is not multipart, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you check the file_type that your server is actually receiving?

```
var_dump($this->upload->data());
```

Then you can check if your mimes is really right.

hope it helps

**@edit**

it seems that you are trying to upload an empty file. If you need your app to accept even empty files, you can do this in mimes.php (line 'txt'):

```
'txt'   =>  array('text/plain', 'application/x-empty'),
```

Comment: Umm, I get:

array(14) {
  ["file_name"]=>
  string(7) "doc.txt"
  ["file_type"]=>
  string(19) "application/x-empty"
  ["raw_name"]=>
  string(3) "doc"
  ["orig_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["client_name"]=>
  string(7) "doc.txt"
  ["file_ext"]=>
  string(4) ".txt"

Comment: Yes, I was testing with empty files! I learn something new. Thanks Gabriel

Comment: Thanks, I tried var_dump the data, and it is showing image/jpeg when uploading png image, anyway solved the problem by adding image/jpeg in mimes.php, under png